# Store a value in an array if this doesn't exist in another array

Tags: node.js, arrays

Hello i'm a beginner in nodejs and i just wanted to know how can i compare 2 array and store the difference into an other array.

i've done this to start :

```
const array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];
const array2 = [5,2,8,9];
const array3 = []; //wanted [1,3,4,6,7,0]
var i=0
array2.forEach(function(element){
  const found = array1.find(element => element !== array2[i])
    array3.push(found)
  i++
})
  console.log(array3)
```

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `filter` and `includes`

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
const array2 = [5, 2, 8, 9]
const array3 = array1.filter((element) => !array2.includes(element))
console.log(array3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement that using `Array.filter` & `Array.includes` function.

```js
const array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];
const array2 = [5,2,8,9];

const result = array1.filter(item => !array2.includes(item));
console.log(result);
```